# Why does this loop wait to finish before adding each result to list? w/ JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, while-loop, rendering

I've made a dead simple loop to demonstrate my question:

```
  var listMaker = function() {
     document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "";
     var i = 1;
     while (i < 150) {
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
        i++;
    }
};​
```

I would think that this function would immediately begin to print off to a list, adding each number one at a time.

Instead, it waits until it finished and then pushed the complete list of 150 numbers.

http://jsfiddle.net/mholubowski/CFQ8K/1/  <- working example, check it out!

Why?

Comment: Since it happens so fast, how can you tell that it's not "adding one item at a time"?

Comment: of course It did, it was in a loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe this was too quick of a loop, but it in fact does not. If you were to change the max value of i to 10,000..it does in fact have a huge delay!

Comment: It adds the list immediately. See it in debug mode

Comment: @Passerby That's what I thought - I even made it an answer on SO before, and then I was yelled at for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser runs JS and does page updates on the same thread. This means it will not update the display while your function is running. So in a sense the items are added one at a time, but you can't see them until the display is repainted after they are all added.

From the user's point of view the browser will be locked up until the JS finishes, so a long-running loop is a bad idea.

You can rewrite your loop using `setTimeout()` and then you can see them appear on the page one at a time.

```
var listMaker = function() {
    var list = document.getElementById('list'),
        i = 1;
    function doNext() {
        if (i < 150){
            list.innerHTML += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
            setTimeout(doNext, 100);
            i++;
        }
    }
    doNext();
};​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CFQ8K/2/

The [`setTimeout()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) queues up execution of a function for later, allowing the current function to complete, in turn allowing the browser to repaint the screen.

The second parameter of `setTimeout()` is the delay in milliseconds - obviously you'd set that as appropriate depending on the effect you are after.

Comment: Thank you... my first ever question and answer on StackOverflow!

Comment: You're welcome. And welcome on board. Further to my answer, note that even if the browser did repaint while running a block of JS, a loop of only 150 iterations will be so fast you wouldn't see the individual items anyway...

Comment: nnnnn what is the benefit of assigning the document.getElementById to a variable outside of the loop?

Comment: Storing the result of `document.getElementById()` in a variable is more efficient because it saves the browser from having to find the element again on every iteration. It matters little in this case, but is a good habit to get into. Imagine if you wanted to set four other properties on the element each time: even ignoring performance the code would be much neater to just repeat the variable name four times rather than repeating `document.getElementById()` four times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt (basically the same thing as the first answer, although arrived at independently nonetheless, but with an Immediately Invoked Anonymous Function (IIAF):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWQWt/)

```
(function() {
    var i = 1,
        list = document.getElementById('list');
        list.innerHTML = "";
    function addToList() {
         if (i < 16) {
             list.innerHTML += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
             i++;
             window.setTimeout(addToList, 300);
         }
    }
    addToList();
})();​
```

Comment: Would you care to explain IIAF's? This is all so darn helpful..I can't thank you guys enough!

Comment: "Anonymous" means it has no name (note the lack of a name - it just has the invocation "(function () { ... })().  It is immediately invoked because after I enclose the function in parentheses I can use the normal () invocation language element for calling a function to cause it to run immediately.  The alternative and more familiar looking means would be a named post invoked function, like function foo() { ... }; foo();